# Typescript React - Conditional rendering using statuses instead of check variable by variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been seen many developers(including me) doing some conditional rendering checking the variables value like this:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>()

  if (!data) return 'Loading...'

  if (data.length === 0) return 'Empty'

  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    return data.map(item => item)
  }

  return null
}
```

But, I don't think it is explicit enough about the page status and about what it should render. So I've been thinking if there is a way of doing something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'

enum PageStatus {
  loading,
  empty,
  withResults
}

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>()

  const status = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return PageStatus.loading
    }

    if (data.length > 0) {
      return PageStatus.withResults
    }

    return PageStatus.empty
  }, [data])

  if (status === PageStatus.empty) {
    return 'Empty'
  }

  if (status === PageStatus.withResults) {
    return data.map(item => item)
  }

  return null
}
```

Unfortunately, Typescript does not recognise the right type for data in the last expression. You can play around and see the error [here in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICySIEcAvnAGZQQhwDkUqGHgCghSAHb5uABRQBzUuRhFcQuHAA2EFABNgY2ZlVwGYGAE9DagO7AYAC2SF86mISHMRaCGMLwZ8uABeOAAKAEoggD4VNS8feABtbQoUbGIYABEUgF0ggmIyCiQAHhQxMwTsyPCRWO9fOF8KZWCaekYQ8KiYtThgNlCAQmTyCJwjXrh%20JSgxOH8FZsIAOk0dPVkJllre-tCRlFXxWXs4aIAGMa21afxZ%20blFpRWbe0dnVy2PLdv7hcLnssTOYjMxsEkcmEdnsQk1nkFAsF-ooiEDwOYrpNfnMeABRdFmYRqb5qGFwlqIh7yAGo14OJBOFyETG9bFwA7LEAoMAhWwMbp8kBQ4k7NkSdTqdxAA). Maybe, there is a way to cast/bind a variable during the run time but I didn't find anything related to this.

So, do you know if that is possible to have conditional renderings oriented to states/status instead of individual variable values? Or even a better way? I appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that TypeScript has no way of relating the correct status to what the results of the function may be. What we need is a union type that equates the status type to what data is actually returned.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'

enum PageStatus {
  loading,
  empty,
  withResults
}

type StatusData<T> = {
  status: PageStatus.loading,
  data: undefined
} | {
  status: PageStatus.empty,
  data: []
} | {
  status: PageStatus.withResults,
  data: T[];
}

const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string[]>();   // just assuming string here

  const statusData = useMemo((): StatusData<string> => {
    if (!data) {
      return {
        status: PageStatus.loading,
        data
      }
    }

    if (data.length > 0) {
      return {
        status: PageStatus.withResults,
        data
      }
    }

    return {
      status: PageStatus.empty,
      data: [],
    }
  }, [data]);

  if (statusData.status === PageStatus.empty) {
    return 'Empty'
  }

  if (statusData.status === PageStatus.withResults) {
    return statusData.data.map(item => item)
  }

  return null
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICySIEcAvnAGZQQhwDkUqGHgCghSAHb5uABRQBzUuRhFcQuHAA2EFABNgY2ZlVwGYGAE9DagO7AYAC2SF86mISHMR5sEjhkKRABEKFAAeABUAPjgAXhU1QkUiAC44GXk-JUIAOk0dPQMjbWCU-DFtJDY9JG13OAAfOLgE-0IUtIUWrJNzSzgi8hSAbQBdWoacI2bMtrkOzKybe0dnV17+lBSwkYBudxE0CDEE1NmYuAAKAEoYqIm1A6P4QfXsYhgg8mGzmgykEISoPkRhEriJ7odjlNAsFvsR6IxzlcUhloeR-jBAfootFbkY1MA2BcAITra53NQU-hKKBiRoUilQ1ondKJbK5XT6Xr0tTrPEUjz0jx8gkXdY5cSyexwKIABjJfLUVPwNLp3MZMxZnUWDiQThchC53N53JYfKF9KVKvJ9PVzLmRC64B6Cr6xTgI0NApY2GewWGl12RhF50ZHxQWUZMWisXaKOy3TM8otSGptJ4AFEnWZhGpzXBg6HghHWVGY7M4wtbDq9a4k5SU8raYXyFkxSAUGBzrYGDd85QQJcjHnLbSJOp1O4gA)

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing with any data, so the type inferred will be `any[] | undefined`. Rather than using type `any`, it would be better to use a type and also initialize with some data. (possibly and empty array)

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'

enum PageStatus {
  loading,
  empty,
  withResults
}

interface dummy {
  name: string
}
const Page = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<dummy[]>([])

  const status = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return PageStatus.loading
    }

    if (data.length > 0) {
      return PageStatus.withResults
    }

    return PageStatus.empty
  }, [data])

  if (status === PageStatus.empty) {
    return 'Empty'
  }

  if (status === PageStatus.withResults) {
    return data.map(item => item)
  }

  return null
}
```

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICySIEcAvnAGZQQhwDkUqGHgCghSAHb5uABRQBzUuRhFcQuHAA2EFABNgY2ZlVwGYGAE9DagO7AYAC2SF86mISHMReylDbokcbUkQMxU1MRQQJAAuOEIYKD1ZdyE0CDE4uBl5OABeOAAKAEpcgD5QuFT0+ABtbQoUbGIYABF6gF1cgmIyCiQAHkCQYOq2kvyRwpE1Soy4imU8mnpGfKLS8rVgNgKAQjryYpwjNTV+JSgxTLkFecIAOk0dROOWKZOtgv2UB-FZezgygAGQ4vU5Ic6XLI3JT3Gz2RzOVwvDwvM74C5XeQ9GF3EzmIzMbC1dqTIwffJzGG5HJ5KHYoi48DmEEnOBojE8ACiTLMwjUKM22wpigWNMx0IZcIcSCcLkILJO7MuXzuIBQYHytgY6y1IEm-LeSrgEnU6ncQA)

Comment: This messes up the loading state

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are relying on Typescript to recognize that `data` is defined off of a function which accepts a function as a parameter that defines `data` (`useMemo`).

And that function in the first parameter which defines `data` is not run in a non `react` environment - it does not have () after it. We know it is run by the framework because we trust `useMemo`, but Typescript doesn't.  Typescript has no awareness on `useMemo` and the dependencies, so there is no way for it to know it is defined... unless it did some deep code diving which I think is beyond the scope.

This is one of the few times I'll use `data!.map(`. I try to avoid it as much as possible, but framework magic is a place I'll use it.